# Browse Happy in 3.2

Tags: wp-admin, admin, wordpress-version

The Browse Happy interruption would only appear to logged-in admin users, correct?  It won't show up on my public facing site?

I can't really fire up IE6 very easily to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it always was and still is only showing in the admin area.

Comment: always was? I thought it was new to 3.2, at least that's what codex seemed to indicate: http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.2

Comment: You would have to manually add Browse Happy to your theme to throw it on the front end ...

Comment: @mgroves Previously, it was in the admin footer.